# I can not access JSON values

Tags: php, json

Need to do an `if()` condition to manipulate some values received by REST FUL.
My REST link gets recent order values.

For example:

```
$params = array(
       'seller'  => 'XXXXXXXX',
       'access_token' => $access_token
    );

   $sales = $meli->get('/orders/search/recent',$params);
```

Sometimes it happens that orders go from 50 records, so I need to add the offset parameter to get those values.

```
$params = array(
           'seller'  => 'XXXXXXXX',
           'access_token' => $access_token,
           'offset' => 50
        );

       $sales = $meli->get('/orders/search/recent',$params);
```

I'm thinking of creating an if condition, in which the parameters shape through the total of requests received by REST FUL. So I'm trying to get the total order value, but my JSON does not return the same so the `IF` condition happens.

For example:

```
$sales['body']->results
```

return the results, no problem about it, But when I try to access the total, a null value is returned.

```
$sales['paging']->total
```

In Postman this values appears.

[image]

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if `$meli` is a guzzle client then you can use `$sales->getBody();` after

Comment: Just like `results`, `paging` is part of the body. So you need `$sales['body']->paging->total`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @aynber

Comment: var_dump is still your friend - `var_dump($sales);`